# Python: Eliminating rows in Pandas DataFrame based on boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame in Pandas like

```
   c1   c2
0  'ab'  1
1  'ac'  0
2  'bd'  0
3  'fa'  1
4  'de'  0
```

and I want it to show all rows such that c1 doesn't contain 'a'. My desired output would be:

```
   c1   c2
2  'bd'  0
4  'de'  0
```

My first attempt was to use df.loc, like this:

```
df.loc['a' not in df['c1']]
```

For searching specific values, df.loc works fine, but for searching based on a False condition ('a' not in df['c1']) it doesn't.

I know I can do the reverse thing. I mean, i can return all rows which contain 'a' in column 'c1', through this code:

```
df.loc[df['c1'].str.contains('a')]
```

But I just can't figure out an elegant/concise way to do the other way around. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `~` to flip your Series of booleans:

```
df.loc[~df['c1'].str.contains('a')]
```

Comment: Works also without the "`.loc`" to condense it even more: `df[~df['c1'].str.contains('a')]`